# mirrormaker2 prometheus metrics

Tags: apache-kafka, prometheus, apache-kafka-connect, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

Based on this link, we can setup a prometheus rule to monitor mm2:
https://github.com/apache/kafka/tree/trunk/connect/mirror#monitoring-an-mm2-process

Tried to apply this rule to a configmap on kubernetes using the confluent connect distribution, but no success neither any error.

Could be deleted or not available those jmx rules on the confluent connect distribution? (we are using the 5.5.0)

Answer (score 2):

Confluent has nothing to do with the issue since MM2 is Apache Licensed.

You'll need to configure your prometheus jmx-exporter with the correct MBeans

I suggest using VisualVM or JMXTerm to view what info is available